# Coding for Markov sources when a state transition is definite?

Tags: markov-chains, coding-theory

I'm reading [section 2.8 of the course Principles of Digital Communications I](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-450-principles-of-digital-communications-i-fall-2006/lecture-notes/book_2.pdf). Suppose I have a Markov chain with a set of state $(a, b, c)$ and $q(a) = q(b) = q(c) = \frac{1}{3}$ (with $q(x)$ is the probability of occurrence $x$) and the state transition is like this:

> a -> b: 100%
>
> b -> a: 50%
>
> b -> c: 50%
>
> c -> a: 50%
>
> c -> b: 50%

$H(X|S) = \frac{2}{3}$. Yet, what is the minimum expected code length of this Markov source? $\frac{2}{3}$ or $1$?

Comment: I think you mean the minimum expected code length?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will make an edit.